# Generating a table but an error occurs

Tags: tables

What is the most efficient way of getting the table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_of_various_materials into LaTeX syntax?

I tried to get it in, and I get the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \texttimes unavailable in enco
ding OT1.
 ...                                              
l.84 Carbon (graphene) & 1×
                            10−8 \\ \hline
```

The table in question has this syntax:

```
%Fig xxxxx table of material resistivity
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
Material                        & $\rho \Omega  \dotsm$ m at 20 \si{\degreeCelsius}                                                    \\ \hline
Carbon (graphene) & 1×10−8 \\ \hline
Silver & 1.59×10−8 \\ \hline
Copper & 1.68×10−8 \\ \hline
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please make your code into a complete, small document demonstrating the issue. This is much more useful than mere fragments. Also, note you can format code by indenting by 4 spaces. Easy way is to highlight and press the {} button in the editor.

Comment: By the way, that error has nothing directly to do with the code you posted. It says what is wrong: `\texttimes` is not defined in the encoding you are using. `\texttimes` is nowhere in your snippet but I guess the `x` uses it? This is why creating a proper Minimal (non-)Working Example is *essential*. Try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{textcomp}`. (The second is enough but the first is far superior to the default OT1 encoding.)

Comment: Hey guys, so the problem was that the "x" was in some way not an "x" - i.e. highlighting it and typing "x" solved the problem. In some cases (siunitx parts) I used something like \times or \multiply or something.

What should I choose as "best answer"..?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to produce a high quality table and the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to format units and produce alignment in cells; a little example that gives you the necessary information to build your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{material resistivity}
\label{tab:matres}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}lSSS}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Material} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\rho\, $\si{(\ohm$\cdot$\meter) at 20 \si{\degreeCelsius} }} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sigma\, $\si[per-mode=symbol]{(S\per\meter) at 20 \si{\degreeCelsius}}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Temperature} \\
& & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries coefficient} \\
& & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{\si{K^{-1}}}} \\
\midrule
Silver & \num{1.59d-8} & \num{6.30d7} & \num{0.0038} \\
Carbon & \num{2.14d-7} & \num{8.24d6} & \num{0.0126} \\
Zinc & \num{1.26d-8} & \num{3.12d8} & \num{0.0672} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's no need for wrapping the numbers in `\num` when you use the `S`-column type. Also, why use `>{\bfseries}` when you use `\bfseries` in all the `\multicolumn`s anyway?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Good to know there's no need for \num; thanks. Perhaps I'll edit my answer later. Reagrding `>{\bfseries}`, it's used to have *all* the entries in the first column boldfaced.

Comment: Reagrding `>{\bfseries}`: Of course. I don't know what I was thinking. `:(`

Comment: Also, is it necessary to load `array`?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg No, it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption), [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), and [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  tableposition = top
]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Material resistivity.}
\label{tab:matres}
 \begin{tabular}{
   l
   S[table-format = 1.2e-1]
   S[table-format = 1.2e1]
   S[table-format = 1.4]
 }
  \toprule
    \mc{Material} 
  & {$\rho$   at \SI{20}{\celsius}}
  & {$\sigma$ at \SI{20}{\celsius}}
  & {Temperature} \\
  &
  &
  & {coefficient} \\
  \midrule
    \mc{---}
  & {\si[inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]{\ohm\m}}
  & {\si[per-mode = symbol]{\siemens\per\m}}
  & {\si{\per\K}} \\
  \midrule
    Silver & 1.59e-8 & 6.30e7 & 0.0038 \\
    Carbon & 2.14e-7 & 8.24e6 & 0.0126 \\
    Zinc   & 1.26e-8 & 3.12e8 & 0.0672 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice the use of `S[table-format = ...]` to get the correct vertical alignment of the numbers.